# Any way to work around linq2Entities exception - Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'.

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, linq

The scenario is

```
void someFunc(object obj1 )
{

  using ( var ctx = getContext() )
  {
    var list = ctx.MyTable.Where ( .... ).OrderBy( ... ).Select (
      x => new PocoObject
      {
          string = x.String,
          ....
          // Command = new MyCommand { prop1 = x } // working code 
          Command = new MyCommand { prop1 = x, objProp = obj1 } // problem line
      }
      ).ToList();

      //list.ForEach( x => x.Command.objProp = obj1 ); working code
  }

}
```

The exception is

Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

changing the problem line with the code marked working code solves the issue

Is there any way to tweak it to make it simpler i.e. without the ForEach at the end ?

Comment: What is the type of `objProp`?

Comment: using "Object" into expression is a bit risky because we don't know an actual type of "Object" you got. Bascially, I think you would cast outside of expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an AsEnumerable() call which will prevent translation to SQL. Which will solve the problem since obj1 cannot be translated to SQL, since it is not a primitive type.

```
void someFunc(object obj1) {
    using (var ctx = getContext()) {
        var list = ctx.MyTable
            .Where ( .... )
            .OrderBy( ... )
            .AsEnumerable() // <-- Everything below is not translated to SQL.
            .Select(x => new PocoObject {
                string = x.String,
                ....
                Command = new MyCommand { prop1 = x, objProp = obj1 }
            })
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says... "Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context".

The initialization of your anonymous object will be done in SQL, which will basically look like this:

```
DECLARE @obj1 (TYPE?) = ...;
SELECT
    ...
    objProp = @obj1
...
```

So unless you can store that value as a SQL variable, this is not going to work.

I don't think there is any workaround, apart for the trivial and what you already tried:

- Use a typed variable, with the type being primitive or enum
- Add the value after the query execution

I suppose in some cases, you *could* consider serializing the value.